# Jenkins uptime - how long since last restart

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to see how long a Jenkins instance/master has been running?

I've tried looking around in "Manage Jenkins" but can't find it there. I know I could log in and check the process on the machine, but is it possible to do it in Jenkins web UI?

This URL shows a white line when it was restarted... but it's not that intuitive.

```
<jenkins-url>/monitoring?part=graph&graph=usedMemory&period=mois
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can run groovy script on Jenkins web-ui from: Manage Jenkins > Script Console, and use Jenkins API. If you want to know how many days Jenkins has been running:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
long lastRestarted = Jenkins.instance.toComputer().getConnectTime()
long now =  System.currentTimeMillis()
println TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(now - lastRestarted)
```

`getConnectTime()` of the master computer should be the time when it restarted.
http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/Computer.html#getConnectTime()

Comment: Ok, we will probably run it as system groovy script to show it a build-name.  Great thanks!

Comment: For version Jenkins ver. 2.32.2 it shows result zero.

Comment: It works for me in Jenkins ver. 2.73.2. How did you run it?

Comment: In this case, you might want to replace `toDays(...)` in the last line with `toMinutes(...)` or whatever your desired resolution is.

Comment: I also am getting 0 from `Computer.getConnectTime()`

Comment: it seems that this only works on non-windows agents.
windows agents return 0, linux and mac agents however return something that looks valid.  unclear why yet

Answer (score 10):

There has been an [`Uptime`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/jenkins/model/Uptime.java) class in Jenkins Core since a long time (Jenkins 1.538). So using the same principle with the script console, the code can be made more readable and robust:

```
println "Jenkins has been started " + (ExtensionList.lookupSingleton(Uptime.class).uptime / 1000 / 60 ) + " minutes ago"
```

Which will show, e.g.:

> Jenkins has been started 175.8678166667 minutes ago

Note: `ExtensionList.lookupSingleton` was introduced in Jenkins 2.87. So if you're using an earlier version, use `ExtensionList.lookup(Uptime.class).get(0)` instead.